# Is it significantly inappropriate to wear clothes bearing the name of University X, when working as an official employee at University Y?

Tags: outward-appearance

I have a hoodie with Dalhousie University written on it (where I used to work), but I now work at Nankai University.

*Question*: Is it significantly inappropriate to wear clothes bearing the name of University X, when working as an official employee at University Y?

I'm thinking I'm overthinking this, and it's a case of "no one cares".  Or, if someone does care, it would only be a momentary blip.  But I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: In that case i'd say that while wearing your Dalhousie hoodie will definitely come across more negatively than positively in your new Uni (I was teased for wearing my BSc alumni hoodie during my MSc), your situational circumstances dictate that "ain't no one got time for that".

Comment: Would you be wearing a Pepsi shirt if you were working for Coca-Cola? As an employee, your situation is significantly different to one of a student.

Comment: @user8001: One key difference is that Pepsi and Coca-Cola are engaged in a zero-sum competition to sell cola.  They are very nearly substitutes for each other, and every time someone buys a Pepsi, Coca-Cola loses a sale (since they could expand almost limitlessly without changing their business model).  Actively expressing any connection to or appreciation of Pepsi would thus be viewed as disloyalty by Coca-Cola.  This is not generally true at universities, and I imagine nobody at Nankai has any feelings of ill will or bitter competition towards Dalhousie.

Comment: As an Bama graduate teaching at a non-SEC school, you'd better believe this past Monday AND Tuesday I was wearing crimson and white :-) Heck, half of my students were too.

Comment: One could argue it's mildly inappropriate, but in no universe is it SIGNIFICANTLY inappropriate.

Comment: One option would be to also buy a hoodie from your current institution. Then at least those you see regularly will know it's not about not supporting Uni Y.

Comment: As far as I know, no one outside of the USA cares about these things.

Comment: PhD students here tend to wear clothes from Universities they visited or graduated from. And actually, some professors do that to, occasionally. Nobody is offended and sometimes it's a great conversation starter. But this is Europe, other cultures might react differently.

Comment: I would be curious to read an answer from the Japanese point of view (the current answers appear to have a USA-flavored point of view). Because as a European I cannot say I have ever paid close attention to where someone's "university hoodie" was said to come from, nor do I really believe the 17 year old high schooler I see really attended [big-name-university] in 1976 (or whatever is written on the hoodie)...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I wrote [my answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/61652/14017) with a fully European point of view. I agree I do not pay close attention; only if I happen to notice, it probably leaves a positive impression. The OP was talking about the clothes of an "official employee", which, to me, rather insinuates someone 25 years of age upwards. Finally, I tend to interpret years printed along with institution names as the institution's year of foundation, but I may be misinterpreting things simply because the concept of a "university class of <year>" does not exist in my country.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper It's true that your answer matches what I would think more closely, sorry for my too-categorical comment. (An answer from the Japanese PoV would still be interesting though.)

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician Universities are in a zero-sum competition for students, faculty members, and grants if they are within the same country. I'd say universities are constantly in the business of selling themselves. I'd definitely find it weird if an employee of an university was promoting a different "brand".

Comment: @user8001: Certainly, there is some competition for faculty members and grants. However, neither is it a goal to dessicate the competitors, nor is there animosity if another institution got the faculty member or grant. In particular, towards students, but also faculty members, the focus on getting best matches between institution and person is much more prevalent than any competition. If a student is interested in topic X, staff from university A will usually point out universities B, C, and D, if A, B, C, and D all deal with X, so the student can get a better overview of the options. ...

Comment: ... Imagine that happening with commercial businesses, one store or company pointing out towards customers that some other stores or companies sell equivalent products! Likewise, a former employee of a company now working for a competitor would usually not receive any advice or other favours from their former employer. At universities, however, maintaining close ties with one's previous institutions (and even advertising them/advertising the new institution of the former employee) is completely normal.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni as far as i know, no one INSIDE of the usa cares about these things. have you ever been to the usa? school rivalries are part of the culture there (just like in any country), but no one ACTUALLY cares. as in, no one is going to be offended. and even if they were, there's absolutely nothing they can do it about it, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I see people do this all the time and it gets the occasional wisecrack but no one really cares.

Comment: @sgroves: "school rivalries are part of the culture there (just like in any country)" - maybe I am oblivious to a part of the local culture in my place, but I perceive the concept of "school rivalries" as something distinctly alien that does not exist in the universities that I have been to in my country.

Comment: So you're saying I can't wear my Miscatonic University Shirt in my University?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are definitely cases in which it would stand out as strange or inappropriate.  You should be careful in cases of a rivalry, since that may be viewed as a significant statement even if you meant nothing by it.  (I'm thinking of Harvard vs. Yale or Illinois vs. Iowa.  Athletic rivalries are particularly troublesome, since students may consider the clothing a sign of active support for the rival university.  No reasonable person could take offense, but not everyone is reasonable.)

It's also risky spending too much time wearing clothing emblazoned with a much more prestigious name than the university you are currently at.  You don't want to look like you are ostentatiously reminding everyone that you graduated from Harvard, unlike the riffraff around you.

I don't think either of these will be an issue for wearing a Dalhousie University hoodie at Nankai University.  If this were in the U.S. or Canada, I don't think it would be a problem at all: the worst case scenario is occasional good-natured teasing, and even that's far from certain.  However, I have no experience with how it might be viewed in China, so it's worth looking into that specifically if you have reason to fear the reactions might be different.

Comment: Iowa vs. ISU is the only Iowa rivalry that will get you angry glares.

Comment: I think you've found the key point here.  They're not adversaries (like the Coke vs. Pepsi example).  If anything, my relationships with the two universities makes them partners.

Comment: I'm in China (but not Chinese) and my impression is that rivalries are much more low-key here than in the US. Then again, Chinese people are typically much more concerned with _image_, so I could imagine some high-level bureaucrat, or even your direct supervisor or coworkers, objecting to the shirt because they _think_ it will give a bad impression, even though in reality nobody actually cares. (Also, even in the US, rivalries are pretty chill except for some big state universities with major athletic programs. You wouldn't get *that* much bad attention for wearing a Yale shirt at Harvard.)

Comment: _Illinois vs Iowa_ --- I think you misspelled "Michigan".

Comment: "not everyone is reasonable" - and there goes my hope for the universitary educational system ...

Comment: Clemson and South Carolina's rivalry would rival those I reckon!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen wait, you actually thought everyone was reasonable ?

Answer (score 12):

In general, research and education is one big (read: global) network. Unlike it may be the case with commercial entities, competition usually happens on friendly terms (you try to be better, but your goal is not to make the competitor disappear) and it does not preclude collaboration.

A few members of one university might get caught up in feelings of rivalry, but I cannot imagine that to have any real effects towards people with links to the so-called "rival" university. We're talking about universities, not elementary schools.

With this in mind, any obvious links to other places (e.g. clothing from another university) seem positive; they underline that the lecturer has gathered some experience at various places, and thereby, indirectly, imply that the university has a well-connected staff with diverse backgrounds.

In the described situation, one thing to note is, however, that there should be some connection to the institution advertised on the clothes. As described above, when I see staff at my university with clothes advertising a different university, I would consider that positive (=> "people with experience and connections"), but if I found out they have not actually been to that place, I *might* feel a bit cheated, even though [I wouldn't care otherwise](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/41433/14017).

Comment: Agree that it is a friendly gesture to wear logo apparel from affiliated institutions. For instance if Humboldt State University had a regular semester-abroad arrangement with Humboldt-Universität zu Berlin.

Comment: The first sentence of your answer gave me some warm feelings.

Answer (score 4):

If there are hot rivalries between the two universities, then it might be taken as offensive or rude.

I am not familiar with the universities you mentioned, but if you were talking about Texas Tech vs. TAMU or Oklahoma University vs. Oklahoma State then I would say definitely wear the local colors.

Further, as a faculty member - you are almost expected to promote the university brand; and it might seem as odd that a faculty member is wearing "opposing" colors - again, the degree of animosity you would face would depend on the degree of competition between the institutions.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that faculty members don't take "rivalries" very seriously, so as a faculty member you should feel free to wear clothing from any university you want.  The one caveat (noted by other posters) is that it is a bit lame if you wear clothing from a prestigious university you have never had any affiliation with.  This is actually good advice for *everyone*; I have run enrichment activities for high school students, and I roll my eyes whenever I see a high school student wearing a Harvard t-shirt.

Mostly I'm answering to share the following anecdote, which illustrates how much you can get away with.  When I was an instructor at MIT, I gave a talk at Caltech.  As a sort of gag gift, they gave me an anti-MIT t-shirt (it says MIT on the front and "because not everyone can get into Caltech" on the back).  I used to wear it when I administered exams.  People were amused, but as far as I can tell no one was genuinely offended.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is appropriate to wear clothes bearing the name of University X.
No one can ask you to wear what you do not want to wear, with a few exceptions.

Comment: There is a difference between "no one can ask that you don't wear this" and "no one will think negatively of you / it will be appropriate to wear this". You should also probably be aware that *many* places have dress codes, from the uniform of the fast food employee to the suit/tie/... dress code of corporate environments. It's not just the army and the police.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi in some cultures (such as the usa), people don't worry if people think negatively of them because of what they wear, because it really doesn't matter. at schools in the us, people wear what they want, and no one cares. of course dress codes may apply at some jobs, but certainly not at schools.

Comment: @sgroves Are you seriously saying that in the USA people don't worry if others think negatively of them because of what they wear (your first sentence)...? You're deluded.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi no, people might care, but it doesn't *matter*. as in, there won't be any consequences for when you wear another school's shirt. so, do it if you want to.